# Issue with if else conditionals in foreach loop in Wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, foreach, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to set up a taxonomy-business-categories.php template for a Wordpress theme.

I have the **custom post type goto_listing**, with **custom taxonomy business-categories**. There are two levels of business-categories, eg

Boatyards, Marinas & Moorings (parent term)

- Boatyards
- Marinas
- Moorings

Cleaning (parent term)

- Fuel Cleaning Service
- Laundry Services

etc.

In my taxonomy-business-categories.php template I have a loop displaying:

Boats (child term)

- Business 1
- Business 2 (premium listing)
- Business 3
- Business 4 (listing with some text manually entered in post excerpt)

Marinas (child term)

- Business 1 (listing with some text manually entered in post excerpt)
- Business 2 (premium listing)
- Business 3
  etc.

All that is working (including links to the single listing for the business)

But **I need to get three things to happen in the foreach loop**.

I need to check if:

1. it is a premium listing (this is a custom field,
   goto_premium_listing) and make that a link to the single listing.
2. does the post have a manually-inserted excerpt, if so show an icon by the listing and make it toggle to show the excerpt.
3. everything else should just be displayed without any icons or links.

I have achieved all three, but not altogether.

I can either get 1 and 3 working together or 2 and 3 working together. Never all three. I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) or various other warnings.

The codes is as follows:

```
<?php 
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
$termchildren = get_term_children( $current_term->term_id, $taxonomyName );
foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    $wpq = array (
    'post_type' => 'goto_listing',
    'taxonomy'=>$taxonomyName,
    'term'=>$term->slug,
    'order'=>'asc'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query ($wpq);
    echo "<h3>$term->name:</h3>"; 
    ?>
    <ul class="goto-leaders">
    <?php if ($query->have_posts() ) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

// BELOW IS THE IF ELSE PART THAT'S NOT WORKING ALL TOGETHER
     <?php
      if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goto_premium_listing ', true));  {  ?>
            <li><span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></span><span><?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?></span></li>
    <?php } 

      else { 
         if ($post->post_excerpt ) { ?>
            <li><span><a href="#" data-toggle="panel-<?php echo $post->ID ; ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i> <?php the_title();?></a></span><span><?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?></span></li>
            <div id="panel-<?php echo $post->ID ; ?>" style="margin-top: 1rem;" class="goto-toggle hide" data-toggler=".hide"><?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?></div>
    <?php  } 

    else { ?>
            <li><span><?php the_title();?></span><span><?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?></li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
   </ul>   

<?php } ?> <!-- end foreach -->
```

I think the problem is with the if else statement within the foreach loop

How do I fix this?

Tracy

UPDATE: Using the following code results in no error warnings but only the first if statement is acted upon, ie I get the icon and toggle text on the business with an excerpt. The rest take the final else statement, ie a plain listing, no icons, not links, nada.

```
 <?php
        if($post->post_excerpt ){ ?>
            <li><span><a href="#" data-toggle="panel-<?php echo $post->ID ; ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i> <?php the_title();?></a></span><span><?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?></span></li>
            <div id="panel-<?php echo $post->ID ; ?>" style="margin-top: 1rem;" class="goto-toggle hide" data-toggler=".hide"><?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?></div>
    <?php  } 
    else {        
        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goto_premium_listing ', true)) {  ?>
            <li><span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></span><span><?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?></span></li>
    <?php }
    else { ?>
            <li><span><?php the_title();?></span><span><?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?></li>
   <?php }}?>
```

The above codes produces this:

[image]

Taking the first child cat Boatyards, you can see Clarke's Court Boatyard, which is a premium listing (with customfield of goto-premium-listing), Grenada Marina is listing with an excerpt, Spice Island Marine Services is a plain old listing.

Grenada Marina and Spice Island Marine Services are working correctly. Clarke's Court Boatyard is a premium listing and should be appearing the same as Spice Island Marine but with a link to the single listing page.

So, it's working correctly apart from putting a link on the premium listing.

UPDATE 2: Here is the output in html format:

```
<ul class="goto-leaders">
<li><span>**Clarkes Court Boatyard**</span><span>439 3939</span></li>
<li><span><a href="#" data-toggle="panel-61"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i> Grenada Marine</a></span><span>443 1667</span></li>
<div id="panel-61" style="margin-top: 1rem;" class="goto-toggle hide" data-toggler=".hide">One-stop shop boatyard providing storage, repair and maintenance services.</div>        
<li><span>Spice Island Marine Services</span><span>444 4257</li>
</ul>  
etc
```

As you can see, it's only the permalink to the premium listing (marked in bold) that has not been actioned.

Comment: Just to be clear, a listing can be either 1, 2 or 3 right?

Comment: Yes, Technoh. The listing will either have no excerpt OR have a (manually inserted) excerpt OR be a premium listing with no excerpt. If it made life simpler I can have the text in the excerpt as custom text field but I thought I may as well make use of what's already there (ie the excerpt).

Comment: you have a rogue `;` after your first if

Comment: Taking that ; out still gives me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in /.../wp-content/themes/Gotoalmanac/taxonomy-business-categories-boatyards-marinas-moorings.php on line 57 which is  `<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

Comment: there is a `}` missing as well, both errors will stop php hence no output. For templating, I prefer using `if(  ):` and `endif;` to close http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php, its much easier to keep track of!

Comment: Hi David, so ... hands up, and surprise surprise I'm not a gifted or experience php coder. I've managed to get the results I have so far from LOT of different places. It's all working so well, apart from getting this working. Where was the missing }? If you check the updated code, have I corrected that with the last double }}? But still not getting the right results. I've also tried elseif's with no result. It's always picking up two of the 3 states, never all three.

Comment: yes you have corrected it. Now your issue is how to explain the issue correctly, you use words like together which suggests all 3 conditions could be true so you have 3 blocks of html to insert. I suspect this is not true, and you only want 1 condition to be true based on whether there is a post excerpt, postmeta with true or else ...

Comment: I thought I'd explained it ok. I need all listings listed under each heading but depending on the conditions (has excerpt or has no excerpt or is premium listing) they output slightly differently. All the listings will meet one of these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your post was really confusing, the picture helps but i'm still not definite what the program flow should be.

What I think the flow should be is as follows:

1. If the post item has both a premium tag and a except -- put a link and a model on the box. --

   2. If just a prem tag--- just a link
   3. if just a excerpt-- just the model
   4. any of the above are not true --- neither link nor model

The code to achieve this is below, see the `&&` operator which basically means `and` so if ( A & B) are both true.

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goto_premium_listing ', true) && $post->post_excerpt):  ?>
    <!-- we place this first, if a post is both a premium lists and has a post excerpt this will run-->
        <li>
            <span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-toggle="panel-<?php echo $post->ID ; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i> 
                    <?php the_title();?>
                </a>
            </span>
            <span>
                <?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?>
            </span>
        </li>

<?php elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goto_premium_listing ', true)):  ?>
    <!-- if the first condition is not true, but this one is this is the html that will be outputted -->
    <!-- this is a premium post without a excerpt for the model -->
        <li>
            <span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            </span>
            <span>
                <?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?>
            </span>
        </li>

<?php elseif($post->post_excerpt ):?> 
<!-- if true, this html will be output.... there is what looks like a boostrap model control
should you wish a link in here replace '#' with <?php the_permalink(); ?>
-->
    <li>
        <span>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="panel-<?php echo $post->ID ; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i> 
                    <?php the_title();?>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?>
        </span>
    </li>

    <div id="panel-<?php echo $post->ID ; ?>" style="margin-top: 1rem;" class="goto-toggle hide" data-toggler=".hide">
        <?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?>
    </div>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- this is the default when the if condition and subsequent elseif conditions are not true -->
        <li>
            <span>
                <?php the_title();?>
            </span>
            <span>
                <?php echo CFS()->get( 'goto_telephone' ); ?>
            </span> <!-- missing span in original code -->
        </li>

<?php endif;?>
```

You may have an issue with your model box, clicking on the link may be disabled by javascript to allow the model to display instead so if this is the case you will need to look into the js and ask a new Q

Comment: No, every listing will be displayed but each 1 will have one of the following states: has excerpt; doesn't have excerpt; is premium listing and has no excerpt. Only the premium has the permalink on the title (name) of the listing. The toggle function works fine on the the ones with excerpt, because it does not have a permalink. The picture shows it working except for the link on the Clark Courts Bay listing, which is a premium listing and so should have the permalink. I trying to display the results with different elements in the <li> is all. Perhaps there's a better way to do it than if/else?

Comment: have you inspected the html to see what the output is? right click in chrome and inspect

Comment: Hi David, I tried your solution but get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ':' in ... on the the line `<?php else if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'goto_premium_listing ', true)):  ?>`. I've updated my question with html output it that helps.

Comment: updated, there should not have been a space between else if